# View Firewalls and virtual networks settings values for storage accounts using azure graph

Tags: azure, graph, azure-storage-account

I would like to write an azure graph query that shows the firewall and virtual networks settings for each storage account.Under public network there are 3 possible values

- enabled for all networks
- enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses
- disabled

would like to project this with name,resourcegroup, typedisplayname, kind.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of below sample **KQL query** to view firewall and virtual networks settings for each storage account:

```json
resources
| where type == "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
| extend firewallSettings = 
    case(
        properties.publicNetworkAccess == "Disabled",
        "Disabled",
        isempty(properties.publicNetworkAccess) or (properties.publicNetworkAccess == "Enabled" and properties.networkAcls.defaultAction == "Allow"), 
        "Enabled for all networks",
        "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses")
| project name, resourceGroup, type, kind, firewallSettings, properties
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Results are as expected